# Microsoft Access saving a query to a table in a macro setting

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm using the dropdown menus to make macros in Microsoft Access, but I'm confused as to how to save a query into a table, overwriting it. The actions are as follows:

```
CopyObject([Example1],Table,[Example2]) #for the purpose of the query
OpenQuery([Query1])
```

But from there I don't know how to get the query saved into a table. SaveObject isn't what I'm looking for, I want it into a table, not saved as a quer Couldn't find any questions on here answering the problem, so I thought I'd ask. Basically, I want to copy-paste a query into a table, as I can do in regular Access, but due to the strict definitions of Access macros I don't think it'll work. I am familiar with SQL, but I'd like to not have to write SQL code as I am doing this multiple times with different names for each table.

Comment: Manual copy/paste in Access utilizes Windows clipboard. I don't know of any way to programmatically select records from a table/query, copy to clipboard, then paste to table. What you should do is INSERT SELECT action SQL.

Comment: Multiple INSERT SELECT actions using different names can be automated with VBA.

Comment: This how I did it. Thank you